# Select query for two weeks ago

Tags: mysql, select, date-arithmetic

In my database table I have a field for date (varchar field to save date in yy-mm-dd format ), now I want to select records for two weeks ago.
How can i do it ?

Comment: Do you mean go back two weeks and select any record that happened in that week?

Comment: The term that you're looking for is "date arithmetic".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I select two weeks ago in MYSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6683768/how-do-i-select-two-weeks-ago-in-mysql)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Implicit date arithmetic is fairly flexible in MySQL. You can compare dates as strings without explicit use of `CAST()` or `DATE()`, but you're trusting MySQL to interpret your format correctly. Luckily for you, it will do just fine with `yy-mm-dd`.

I would recommend using `BETWEEN` and `INTERVAL` so that your query is easily readable; for example:

```
SELECT * FROM Holidays 
WHERE Date BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND NOW();
```

The only trick with `BETWEEN` is that you have to put the lower bound first and the upper bound second; for example, if you write `BETWEEN 5 AND 2`, this always evaluates to `FALSE` because there is no value that can be greater than or equal to 5 while also being less than or equal to 2.

[Here's a demo of the query in action at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9e40/2/0), and a list of the [recognized `INTERVAL` expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) in MySQL.

Note that the parentheses around the expression `NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY` are not required but I would recommend using them here purely for the sake of clarity. It makes the predicate clause just a little bit easier to read in the absence of proper syntax highlighting, at the expense of two characters.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be using date types to store dates, but being that's not the case, you should look into casting to date then comparing.

```
select * from yourtable where cast (yourdate as Date) BETWEEN Date_Add(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -21 Day) and Date_Add(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -14 Day)
```

Note, this is untested and may need a little tweaking, but should give you a general idea of what you need to do.

Also, if it's possible, you should really look into converting the varchar field to a date field....they have date types to prevent this sort of thing from happening, although i know changing field types isn't always a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do with `ADDDATE` to get 14 days ago. compare **string** with **date** will work.

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE your_date >= ADDDATE(NOW(), -14) AND your_date < NOW()
```

Comment: Note, date is stored as varchar, so cast would have to be done first.

Comment: you can do compare date by varchar

Answer (score 0):

I use this for select data in past of past

```
SELECT * FROM Holidays 
WHERE a.dDate >= DATE( NOW( ) ) - INTERVAL 14
DAY AND a.dDate <= DATE( NOW( ) ) - INTERVAL 8
```